# SQL multiplying two columns from two different tables

Tags: sql, multiplication

i have two tables

```
Items                                        Inventory
-----------                                  -----------
Unit_Price                                   Item_Code
Item_Code                                    Order_Num
Item_Type                                    Item_In_Stk
```

i am trying to calculate all the inventory items that have a unit price over $25
so im doing this by multipplying Unit_Price and Item_In_Stk

here is my code

```
SELECT SUM(Unit_Price * Items_In_STk)
FROM Item, Inventory
WHERE Unit_Price > 25.00
AND Item.ITEM_CODE IN(3177,45219,23456);
```

i put the `Item_Code` numbers in the `AND` operator that are over 25.00 but i did the math and im getting the wrong answer. How should i rearrange this because i think the logic behind it is right

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT items.item_code, SUM(Unit_Price * Items_In_STk)
FROM Items JOIN Inventory
on items.item_code = inventory.item_code 
WHERE Unit_Price > 25.00 
AND Items.ITEM_CODE IN(3177,45219,23456)
group by items.item_code
```

You are missing a `group by` clause on item_code. Also, you were missing a `join` clause.

Edit: If you only need the `sum` for all the 3 item codes, you can do

```
SELECT SUM(Unit_Price * Items_In_STk)
FROM Items JOIN Inventory
on items.item_code = inventory.item_code 
WHERE Unit_Price > 25.00 
AND Items.ITEM_CODE IN(3177,45219,23456)
```

Comment: i got the right values with your code thanks but im now trying to add all 3 values up??

Comment: look at the modified version.